# MPI and D: Linker Options

Tags: linker, parallel-processing, d, mpi, mpiexec

I'm trying to use MPI with the D programming language.  D fully supports the C ABI and can link with and call any C code.  I've done the obvious stuff and translated the MPI header to D.  I then translated [a test program from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface#Example_program) to D.  I compiled it with the following command:

`dmd test.d -L-lmpistubs`

It works when I just run `./test`, and prints:

`0: We have 1 processors`

However, when I run with `mpiexec -n 8 test`, it prints nothing.  My understanding is that MPI executables require a bunch of weird linking options, which is why tools like `mpicc` exist to automate the process.  However, this doesn't help me if I'm trying to use MPI in D.  I assume it's because I'm not using the right linker options.  Can someone please tell me what `mpicc` does and how I can make DMD do the same thing?

Edit:  I've found the answer using `mpicc -showme`.  This shows what commands `mpicc` forwards to `gcc`.  However, I also realized I did the header file translation wrong.  Next question:  [How do to it right.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945728/mpi-h-using-a-type-w-o-defining-it)

Comment: did you use extern(C) when you were translating?

Comment: have you tried running `strace -f mpicc test.c` or something like that, to look for the linker options? I assume it's calling `ld` or something as a child process.

Answer (score 2):

mpicc is common name of different scripts and even programs. 
Some of them have option like `-echo`, `-show`, `-compile-info`, `-link-info` or `-showme` or environment option to show what is actually called.

Try to check what is it actually with

```
 file -k `which mpicc`
```

If it is script, it can be written in sh, bash, perl, python. You can easily view it and find correct option.
If it is an program, try to run

```
 strings `which mpicc`
```

Sometimes `strings` can extract option names and/or environment variables which controls the work of script.

Also, most of mpicc check CC env variable to get name of compiler. You can write a script or a program which will just print its arguments and set CC env to this program.