# mpi.h: Using a type w/o defining it?

Tags: c, header, parallel-processing, d, mpi

I'm trying to translate the important parts of OpenMPI's mpi.h to the D programming language so I can call it from D.  (HTOD didn't work at all.)  I can't wrap my head around the following bits of code:

```
typedef struct ompi_communicator_t *MPI_Comm;
OMPI_DECLSPEC extern struct ompi_communicator_t ompi_mpi_comm_world;
OMPI_DECLSPEC extern struct ompi_communicator_t ompi_mpi_comm_self;
OMPI_DECLSPEC extern struct ompi_communicator_t ompi_mpi_comm_null;
```

The problem is that `ompi_communicator_t` is never defined in mpi.h and mpi.h doesn't include any other file besides stddef.h, which clearly doesn't contain a definition.  (The comment says it's included for `ptrdiff_t`.)  These are the only four lines in mpi.h that contain the string `ompi_communicator_t`.  Where is the definition of this struct coming from?  Are there any tricks I should be aware of where types can appear out of thin air?  (There are several other structs like this, but this is the first one I stumbled upon.)

Comment: Looks like a typical opaque type. You should be able to safely replace it with anything, as the library only cares about addresses.

Comment: @dsimcha: nice work! would you share your source and how you compiled the example program? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pointer to the struct, which internals are not visible outside the OpenMPI. Use any type which can hold a pointer, e.g. (in C) `void*`.

Comment: Thanks.  I never realized that such undeclared-but-used structs are legal in C (they aren't in D).  I just made a completely bogus struct to shut the D compiler up about it not being defined since, as you and CyberShadow mention, it's really all just memory addresses anyhow.

Comment: I've always used empty structs in these cases: `struct test{}`

Comment: @jpf:  That's exactly what I ended up doing.