# MPI for the D programming language

Tags: mpi, d

This question is related to this question: [MPI and D: Linker Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944691/mpi-and-d-linker-options)

I am trying to get MPI working from D. There are several posts to be found in the net, but none I found did actually work... So here is what I did so far:

I took the mpi.d from here https://github.com/1100110/OpenMPI/blob/master/mpi.d and set up a minimal program:

```
import mpi;
import std.stdio;

void* MPI_COMM_WORLD = cast(void*)0;

int main(string[] args)
{

  int rank, size;
  int argc = cast(int)args.length;
  char *** argv = cast(char***)&args;


  MPI_Init (&argc, argv);   /* starts MPI */
  MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);    /* get current process id */
  MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);    /* get number of processes */
  writefln( "Hello world from process %d of %d", rank, size );
  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

I compile with

```
dmd test_mpi.d -L-L/usr/lib/openmpi -L-lmpi -L-ldl -L-lhwloc
```

or

```
gdc test_mpi.d -pthread -L/usr/lib/openmpi -lmpi -ldl -lhwloc -o test_mpi
```

and run with

```
mpirun -n 2 ./test_mpi
```

This is the error I get:

```
[box:1871] *** An error occurred in MPI_Comm_rank
[box:1871] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[box:1871] *** MPI_ERR_COMM: invalid communicator
[box:1871] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 0 with PID 1870 on
node bermuda-iii exiting improperly. There are two reasons this could occur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.

2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"

This may have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[box:01869] 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
[box:01869] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

Obviously I do call MPI_Init and MPI_Finalize. So what am I missing?

Comment: Sooo...  Is it still working from when I left it there?  I do accept pull requests!

Comment: I am still testing... so far this simple example wroks, but more complex stuff doesn't so I am trying to figure out why...

Comment: If it's easy for you, pull anyways and let me take a look.  Maybe I'll be able to spot it.   (if it's not don't worry about it.  I'll update that at some point.)

Comment: ping, maybe?  Got an update for me?

Comment: @0b1100110: I didn't work on this for a while as you might have noticed ;) Anyways, I would like to pull and see if some afternoon I play with it. I'll send you an Email

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Open MPI C communicator handles are pointers to the real communicator structures. `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is a pointer to the precreated world communicator structure and not a NULL pointer as you define it. That's why Open MPI aborts in the call to `MPI_COMM_RANK` - it is equivalent to calling `MPI_Comm_rank(NULL, &rank)` in C.

If you take a look at [line 808](https://github.com/1100110/OpenMPI/blob/master/mpi.d#L808) of `mpi.d`, you would notice that `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is already defined as:

```
MPI_COMM_WORLD      = cast(void*) &(ompi_mpi_comm_world),
```

So your code should work if you remove the line where you redefine `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.

Comment: Doh! I put that to compile with another version of mpi.d and forgot to delete it! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are not casting `string[]` to `char***` right. You should do this instead:

```
import std.string, std.algorithm, std.array;

char** argv = cast(char**)map!(toStringz)(args).array.ptr;
MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
```

Here's how it works:

- Maps `toStringz` on each `args` element.
- Because map returns range, we use `array` to have array of it.
- Getting array pointer.

Comment: there is a parenthesis missing. Before map?

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing that out. But unfortunately it doesn't fix the issue... :(